# How to make react-router's useSearchParams type-safe by overriding the type?

Tags: typescript, react-router

I would like to handle useSearchParams in react-router in a type safe manner.

Specifically, I want to do the following

```
declare module "react-router-dom" {
  interface URLSearchParams {
    get(name: MyQueryParams): string | null;
  }
}
```

However, doing this caused the problems of "function definitions other than get disappearing" and "setSearchParams arguments causing type errors".

How can I do this correctly?

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-shtern-kso11t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark
(fixed!)

```
type MyQueryParams = "aaa" | "bbb";

declare module "react-router-dom" {
  interface URLSearchParams {
    get(name: MyQueryParams): string | null;
  }
}

function Sample() {
  const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();

  // 1. searchParams.get is not type safe
  //    so I want to type URLSearchParams
  //    only for this file.
  console.log(searchParams.get("aaa"));

  const onClick = () => {
    // 2. but error occurs on this line
    setSearchParams(searchParams);
  };

  return <button onClick={onClick}>{searchParams.get("aaa")}</button>;
}
```

Comment: [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) isn't a `react-router-dom` object or thing they type or define. What are you trying to accomplish? Can you [edit] to more clearly explain the use case and provide a better [mcve]?

Comment: @Drer Reese  Thank you for poiting out. I add minimal reproucible example. https://codesandbox.io/embed/stupefied-shtern-kso11t?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Perhaps I just don't understand what you are doing, or trying to do, with the code in the sandbox, but after (1) removing the conflicting v5 `@types/react-router` and `@types/react-router-dom` dependencies (*v6 is written entirely in Typescript*), (2) removing the unnecessary duplicate `react-router` dependency (*`react-router-dom` re-exports **all** of `react-router`*), and (3) comment out where the code is attempting to redeclare the `URLSearchParams` interface, there are no issues/warnings/errors with the code.

Comment: @Drew Resse Thank you! I think there was something I didn't ask well here either... I ended up using other solution to accomplish type safe react-router,,